# 実行したSQL文をlog4jでログ出力したい

Tags: java, spring, logging

Aspectを使用して特定メソッド前後にアプリケーションログを出力しています。
ここに、JdbcTemplateで実行されたSQL文をログに出力しようとしています。
SQL文以外のログは全て正常に出力されています。
log4jdbcは使用していません。

ログを取得する場所としては、下のLogApクラス側を修正するか、
TestDaoクラス内にLoggerで個別ログを記述するかの２か所ではないかと考えていますが、
どのようにすれば実行SQL文が取得できるか解決できませんでした。
アドバイスをお願いします。

追記：ログレベルをtraceにしてもメソッド前後のアプリケーションログしか出力できないため、こちらに相談しています。

---

欲しいログ
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE name="testName";
もしくはプレースホルダ付きSQL文とパラメータのセット

---

log4j.xml

```
<logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" additivity="false">
   <level value="debug" />
   <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
</logger>
<logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils" additivity="false">
   <level value="debug" />
   <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
</logger>
<root>
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
</root>
```

ログ出力定義

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class LogAp {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogAp.class);

    @Before("execution(* jp.co.test.*.*(..))")
    public void aa(JoinPoint jp) {
        log.debug(jp.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName());
    }

    @After("execution(* jp.co.test.*.*(..))")
    public void bb(JoinPoint jp) {
        log.debug(jp.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName());
    }
}
```

DAOクラス

```
package jp.co.test;
public class TestDao {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbc;
   
    public void selectName() {
        jdbc.queryForList("SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE name=?","testName");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL本文は [`debug`レベルで出力されます](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.3.23/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L641-L644)が、 prepared statement の値は [`trace` レベルで出力される](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.3.23/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/StatementCreatorUtils.java#L226-L231)ようですので、次のような設定になります:

```xml
  <logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" additivity="false">
    <level value ="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
  </logger>
  <logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils" additivity="false">
    <level value ="trace" />
    <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
  </logger>
```

結果:

```
Executing prepared SQL query
Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE name=?]
Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [testName], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
```

Comment: 説明足りずすみません。traceは試して効果ありませんでした。

Comment: 回答するに当たって検証したコードが[こちら](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/main/jaso91830)になりまして、回答に記載した通りの出力が得られています(※ 検証はSpring Boot で実施しました)。ログが出力されていないとすると、質問文中にある箇所以外が原因の可能性がありますので、[再現可能なコード](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)を含めるのが良いかと考えます。また、利用しているプロダクトのバージョンも有用な情報なので、質問文中に含めるのが良いかと考えます。

Comment: 構成がmavenではなく、通常の動的PJのため設定に問題があり、実現が難しいのかもしれません。今回は諦めて別の方法を考えます。丁寧なアドバイスとコード作成に感謝し、今後に役立てます。